# How to fetch from twitter API only if it has media data

Tags: ruby, api, twitter

I want to fetch all tweets based on a hashtag but I only want to fetch tweets that have `media` In the documentation there is no specification regarding query only if there is media in the tweet, for example, something like `media: true` can this be done in the query?

```
client.search("#technology", { tweet_mode: "extended", include_entities: true, fromDate:"201801071200",toDate:"201802071200", entities: true})
```

Is I add `media: true` would that work ? and if not how to go about only fetching if there is media on the tweet

Answer (score 0):

I guess `filter:media` is the correct operator.

something like

```
client.search("#technology filter:media", { tweet_mode: "extended", include_entities: true, fromDate:"201801071200",toDate:"201802071200", entities: true})
```

Here is the reference: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/guides/standard-operators. Hope, that helps.

--

If you are searching with Premium search APIs then operator changes to `has:media`: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/guides/premium-operators

Overview: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/overview

Comment: can I also filter `date`? I think `fromDate:` and `toDate` are also Premium features

Comment: `superhero since:2015-12-21` containing “superhero” and sent since date “2015-12-21” (year-month-day).

`puppy until:2015-12-21` containing “puppy” and sent before the date “2015-12-21”.

Comment: `since` and `until` are part of standard operators. along with `filter:media`

Comment: Date filters may not be effective on the standard search API - only 7 days history of Tweets are available.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, there is a filter has:media which can be used to retrieve tweets that have an attached media. But it is only available to premium and enterprise operators.

Here is the reference

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/guides/premium-operators

Otherwise you can always fetch tweets and filter the ones which have media by fetching tweets with extended entities. From the entities property you can check if the media property is available and has values. If it does, you know you have a tweet with media.